# npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency during npm install

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-dom

While running npm install on my React app, I see below logs. However, the npm install completes and I can see deps added under node_modules
Also, my app does start up. My question is if it is fine to ignore these warnings for now.

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.56
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"~17.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN   32 more (@myframework/aria-announcer, @myframework/button, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0" from @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.56
npm WARN node_modules/@myframework/pagination/node_modules/@material-ui/lab
npm WARN   @material-ui/lab@"4.0.0-alpha.56" from @myframework/pagination@33.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@myframework/pagination
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.0" from @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.56
npm WARN   node_modules/@myframework/pagination/node_modules/@material-ui/lab
npm WARN     @material-ui/lab@"4.0.0-alpha.56" from @myframework/pagination@33.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/@myframework/pagination
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.56
npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"~17.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN   27 more (@myframework/aria-announcer, @myframework/button, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.8.0" from @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.56
npm WARN node_modules/@myframework/pagination/node_modules/@material-ui/lab
npm WARN   @material-ui/lab@"4.0.0-alpha.56" from @myframework/pagination@33.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@myframework/pagination
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.8.0" from @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.56
npm WARN   node_modules/@myframework/pagination/node_modules/@material-ui/lab
npm WARN     @material-ui/lab@"4.0.0-alpha.56" from @myframework/pagination@33.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/@myframework/pagination
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore these warnings as npm is overriding the peer dependency. the warning is about version mismatch for the package `@material-ui/lab`. as it expects react version `^16.8.0` but it found react version `17.0.2`. and other is same for react-dom. you can ignore it. but it's better to use the version that's other package require it to be. you can downgrade your react and react-dom version to resolve this  warnings

Comment: Thanks a lot...Actually thing is most of my other app dependencies (e.g. craco, module federation related, etc) require React v 17...so that is the reason, I cannot downgrade to React v16

Comment: Can I fix these warnings using either "overrides" OR "resolutions" in package.json ?

Comment: @copenndthagen if those other libraries need react v 17 then you can just ignore those warnings untill and unless it's affecting any functionality of your webapp. as for material ui lab that you are using is deprecated so i would suggest you use/switch to material ui v5 and update your codebase accordingly. or you can just ignore these warnings

Comment: Sure....so there is no way to suppress this warnings....The best I can do is just Ignore them (until they coz any functional issues)

Comment: that's what `--legacy-peer-deps` flag does. install material-ui/lab with legacy peer deps flag that might suppress the warnings.